# ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation with AR 5.1 and Sinatra 2

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, sinatra-activerecord

we are using:

```
gem 'sinatra', '~> 2.0.0'
gem 'activerecord', '~> 5.1.1'
gem 'sinatra-activerecord', '~> 2.0.13'
```

The thing is that with ActiveRecord 5 we cannot pass a migration:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation: Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `ar_internal_metadata` (`key`, `value`) VALUES ('environment', 'default_env')
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Mysql2::Error: Field 'created_at' doesn't have a default value
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

AR5 adds a new table called ar_internal_metadata to prevent destructive rakes in production:
http://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/06/07/rails-5-prevents-destructive-action-on-production-db.html

As you can see in logs value is receiving Null and it raises doing the migration pending.

We have tried adding this ENV_VARS but nothing:
`DISABLE_DATABASE_ENVIRONMENT_CHECK=1`

Can anyone help us with this, please?

Comment: Do you have a join table in your app?

Comment: No @hashrocket, it has three tables. Neither of them are a join table.

Comment: Do any of your tables contain :null => false?

Comment: One, just the column I want to remove in the migration. But the error is of an internal table. We cannot change it.

Answer (score 0):

Change the db column that has `:null => false` to `:null=> true`.

The reason this is happening is because newer versions of MySql turn on "strict mode" by default. Any column with :null=> false requires that column to be populated with some kind of data. It seems your is empty, so your getting an error.

Comment: It has a default value (false), but it is not that problem. It is in other table.

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: I remove that column in the migration and it does it well. But it raises an error later for `ar_internal_metadata` table. It does it with any new migration.

Comment: Are you trying this in a production environment?

Comment: No, in development